# Preg_match возвращает false

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, controller, action

Пишу маршрутизатор, использую регулярное выражение. На выходе preg_match возвращает false.
routes.php

```
<?php
use test_shop\Router;
Router::add('^$', ['controller' => 'Main', 'action' => 'index']);
Router::add('^(?P<controller>[a-z-])+/?(?<action>[a-z-]+)?$');
```

Router.php

```
<?php
namespace test_shop;
class Router
{
protected static $routes = [];
protected static $route = [];

public static function add($regexp, $route = [])
{
    self::$routes[$regexp] = $route;
}

public static function getRoutes()
{
    return self::$routes;
}

public static function getRoute()
{
    return self::$route;
}

public static function dispatch($url)
{
    if (self::matchRoute($url)){
        echo 'OK';
    }else {
        echo 'NO';
    }
}

public static function matchRoute($url)
{
   foreach (self::$routes as $pattern => $route) {
       if (preg_match("#{$pattern}#", $url,$matches)) {
           foreach ($matches as $k => $v) {
               if (is_string($k)) {
                   $route[$k] = $v;
               }
           }
           if (empty($route['action'])){
               $route['action'] = 'index';
           }
           debug($route);
           return true;
       }
   } return false;
}
}
```

На выходе `http://localhost/test_shop/` выдаёт NO

Версия PHP 7.0

Если написать `if(!preg_match ....`
то На выходе `http://localhost/test_shop/` выдаёт

```
Array
(
   [controller] => Main
   [action] => index
)
OK
```

Если в url указать дальнейший путь, то значение в массиве не меняться

```
class App
{
public static $app;

public function __construct()
{
    $query = trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '/');
    session_start();
    self::$app = Registry::instance();
    $this->getParams();
    new ErrorHandler();
    Router::dispatch($query);
}

protected function getParams(){
    $params = require_once CONFIG . '/params.php';
    if(!empty($params)) {
        foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
            self::$app->setProperty($k,$v);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Если корень вашего сайта `http://localhost/test_shop/`, то удаляйте его из `$url`, а потом уже проверяйте на совпадения с регуляркамию

Comment: А покажите, как урл добываете, по моему дело в том, что урл достаётся не так, как вы хотите

Comment: debug($url) выдал index.php

Comment: @НикитаПавлов сверху указал куда ведет метод dispatch($url)

Comment: @Эдуард передал этот аргумент значение false. В браузуре NO. 
цель что-бы в строке можно было прописать к примеру http://localhost/test_shop/page/veiw и debug($route) вернул бы мне массив `[controller] => page` `[action] => index` сейчас по этой ссылке он возвращает массив  `[controller] => Main` `[action] => index` пустой массив и NO

Comment: также если задебажить `debug($url)` по этой  `localhost/test_shop/page/veiw` ссылке то $url вернёт `index.php&page/view`

Comment: @Эдуард подставил пример теперь переменная debug($route) возвращает массив
    `[controller] => localhost`
    `[action] => clock_shop`
и

`OKNO`

Comment: @VladimirsAlesejevs вроде бы так: __[смотреть демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f0f90804ebd0e5d9641bd7dc7e689f8140c2dde)__

Comment: Скорее всего в файле .htaccess что то не то!

Comment: Не подскажите, что там не так?